# Copying records from MS Access database into SQLite database using CSV format. Need an alternative

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, csv

I have a database on MS Access with one table containing 25 fields. It contains 1000 to 10,000 or more records (The number of records is an approximation. The company I'm working for has a huge amount of data though).

The company wants to get access to this data (for read-only purposes) on their Android phones. They require this data to be transferred to the phone through a wired connection (no wifi).

Here's how my solution works:
I export the MS Access database table as a CSV file. Then, I parse this CSV file 
using java code, and then insert each record into an SQLite database.

As the records are updated often, we'll have to export a new CSV once every week and refresh the SQLite database.

Here's the issue with my solution:

1. Takes twice as much storage space: As I understand it, there are two versions of the same table stored on the device - one, as a CSV file, and another as SQLite database.
2. It requires time to refresh the SQLite database because the 10,000 records need to be deleted and then inserted back.

Someone suggested me to convert the .mdb file into a jar file and run select queries on that jar instead of using SQLite. But I don't understand how it works. Someone please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Does the file have to go to the Android phone in form of a CSV or can it go in the form of a SQLite DB? Also, can you normalize the table at all - that is, break the 25 columns into smaller tables? Seems like the more you can offload to the PC the better.

Comment: yes, it can go in the form of sqlite. I tried looking up for a way to do that after I read your comment. The thing is that the client will have to do the conversion often as their database gets updated quite frequently. The method I found for conversion of .mdb into .sqlite is based on command line which the client will not be able to handle.. The conversion to csv, on the other hand, is as simple as clicking a button, so I'd prefer that for the client.

Comment: Now I am looking for java library that can do this conversion, so that all the client has to do is to drop the .mdb into the android folder..

Comment: My new strategy is to not use sqlite at all, as the insertion of thousands of records from csv into sqlite is an overhead. I am fetching the required record direcctly from csv. What do you think @BAReese